# GET request inside POST API endpoint interferes with 'respond_with'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rest

After reading [Stored Android Accounts for Authentication of Rails + Devise Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183300/stored-android-accounts-for-authentication-of-rails-devise-accounts) I'm trying to setup a Rails 3 API endpoint that can verify an OAuth obtained token through a GET request to Google.

I've configured the route as:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    get 'auth/verify' => 'omniauth_verifications#verify_token'
    ...
  end
end
```

And in `api/v1/omniauth_verifications_controller.rb` I've defined the method as:

```
respond_to :json

def verify_token
  token = params[:token]

  response = RestClient.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo", { params: { access_token: token }})

  if response.code == 200
    data = JSON.parse(response.to_s)

    @user = User.find_for_verfied_token_response(data.symbolize_keys)
  end

  respond_with @user
end
```

The problem is, that the response I'm getting when hitting the endpoint is `500 Internal Server Error` with a `Template Missing` message

If I comment out the line with `RestClient.get` and instead do `respond_with User.find(1)` the repsonse is `201` with the json formatted user-object returned as expected.

Why is Rails insisting on rendering a template even though I'm explicitly telling it to `respond_with @user`? Is the `RestClient` taking over my response or what's happening?

I've also tried raising an exception after the `RestClient.get`, but the output is still `Template Missing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the [HTTParty](http://johnnunemaker.com/httparty/) gem which fixed the issue with the request overriding the `respond_with`.

I had to go back to the OAuth2 playground to figure out Google now requires an `Authorization` header too when requesting the user info.

This is what I ended up with:

```
def verify_token
  token = params[:token]

  response = HTTParty.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo", headers: {"Access_token" => token, "Authorization" => "OAuth #{token}"})

  if response.code == 200
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)
    @user = User.find_for_verfied_token_response(data.symbolize_keys)
  end

  respond_with @user || {}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to :json

def verify_token
  token = params[:token]

  response = RestClient.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo", { params: { access_token: token }})

  if response.code == 200
    data = JSON.parse(response.to_s)

    @user = User.find_for_verfied_token_response(data.symbolize_keys)

    render :json => @user.to_json
  else
    render :json => { }
  end     
end
```

Comment: Yes I have, it still responds with `500 - Template Error`

Comment: I updated my code. Although I don't think it works. It solves an issue for when the response code doesn't equal 200.